# can't access/download a generated folder that is inside a Docker container using REST API calls

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been trying to solve this issue for quite some time, and I'm pretty sure it's just a really stupid mistake but I'm really giving up on life.

**Background:** I have a Flask python app providing RESTful services. This app is running inside a docker container. some GET functions return Json responses and they're simple and work fine. some, however, are a bit more complex. There's a file inside the docker container called "generated" what **get_files** does here is it compresses it in a Zip file, then downloads the generated zip file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
import zipfile

app = Flask(__name__)
#app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

#gets all elements 
@app.route('/elementsdb/ecu',methods=['GET']) 
def getAllElements(): 
     return jsonify({'ecus':elementsDB})  

#-------------------------------------------#
#Get files
@app.route('/get_files', methods=['GET'])
def download():
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile('gen.zip', mode = 'w')
    zf.write('generated/one.c')
    zf.write('generated/two.c')
    zf.write('generated/three.c')
    zf.write('generated/four.h')
    zf.close()
    return send_from_directory("/Users/abeer/downloads/testD", "gen.zip", as_attachment=True)
```

**Issue:** /get_files works fine when running independently on localhost. http://localhost:5000/get_files but because the app is in a docker container, it downloads the file inside the docker image. When I try to access the file via postman or curl, I get a [404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UWs8.png) I've also tried to change the path to download the file outside the image but that doesn't work either. It's probably a publish/expose port thing in Docker but I'm so clueless in that matter.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7
ADD . /todo
WORKDIR /todo
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  build: .
  command: python -u flaskdb.py
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
    - .:/todo
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: mongo:3.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little too late to help you, but for others about to give up on life, it doesn't work on docker because the path `/Users/abeer/downloads/testD` does not exist on the container, hence the 404

You need to tell the container to use that path by mapping the path to it using [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), then it will work